# Can I initialize an empty 2D C string like this?

Tags: c, arrays, string, c-strings

Can I initialize an empty 2-dimentional C string like this?

```
int function(void){
  char s[50][50]={{}};
}
```

I'm not sure if string s will be initialized as empty when it's defined in a function like this.

Comment: First try to *build* it (with extra warning enabled). Does it build without errors or warnings? Then that's a good sign that it might work as you think. Evne if it's not conclusive, at least try it first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you may not, if you want your code to be portable C:

```
% gcc -pedantic-errors -c init.c 
init.c: In function ‘function’:
init.c:2:19: error: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces [-Wpedantic]
   char s[50][50]={{}};
                   ^
```

It is a GCC extension. However you can add a *single* zero in the braces:

```
char s[50][50] = {{0}};
```

or even within just one set of braces:

```
char s[50][50] = {0};
```

it will find the first scalar element and initialize it with the given  value, and rest of the elements not explicitly initialized will be initialized as if they had a zero initializer. (Note: you could use say *42* for the one element, and rest of them would be still initialized to zero).

Or, since these are arrays of *`char`*, you can use a string in braces:

```
char s[50][50] = {""};
```

This will initialize `s[0]` with the empty string.

---

The empty initializer (`{ }`)  of GCC is needed for *another extension* - initialization of zero-length flexible array members. It does not exist just to be a generic shorthand.

Standard C does not support initialization of flexible array members, nor does it support arrays of length zero.

Comment: Notably, the zero-length arrays in GCC is an obsolete non-standard feature. It existed pre-C99 to fix the old "struct hack" defect of the language. But after C99 provided standard support, the GCC feature is no longer needed and should not be used in new code - nor should the empty initializer list.

Comment: @Lundin it is needed to initialize a FAM in auto of length zero.